# VSCode-Server + LateXWorkshop. Can't see the tab pdf preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I have [vscode-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server) in a docker container, exposed on the internet through reverse proxy, with LatexWorkshop and texlive installed.

Everything seems to be ok, but I can't see the pdf preview in the tab, there is the pdf viewer, but nothing inside, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14QJ0.png). If I go to get the file, the pdf is generated normally.

In the LatexWorkshop log, there are these lines:

```
[Commander] VIEW command invoked with mode: tab.
[Manager] Current workspace folders: ["file://%WS1%","file://%WS2%"]
[Manager] Found root file from active editor: %WS2%/aaa.tex
[Manager] Keep using the same root file: %WS2%/aaa.tex
[Structure] Structure updated with 0 root sections for %WS2%/aaa.tex .
[Viewer][Panel] Internal PDF viewer at https://example.com/proxy/40451/viewer.html?file=pdf..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx .
[Cacher][Watcher] Watched %WS2%/aaa.pdf .
[Viewer] Open PDF tab for file://%WS2%/aaa.pdf
[Viewer] Handle data type: open
```

If I click the `file://%WS2%/aaa.pdf` address, [it opens a tab, all black, nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqGE.png), different from before where you could at least see the pdf viewer.

If I click the `https://example.com/proxy/40451/.....` address, it correctly shows the [pdf in a browser tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwJnY.png).

So I have a problem with the tab preview, same problem on Firefox and Chrome.

Do you happen to know why?

Thanks

Comment: @KJ It was just an example to mask my domain, on which is hosted the vscode-server service.

Comment: @KJ Hmm I see. So vscode-server or the Latexworkshop extension don't have a built-in pdf viewer to show it in a tab, inside the service? Is it correct?
Edit: Just to clarify. I'm trying to achieve an Overleaf type of workflow. So remotely, in browser, but with vscode.

Comment: @KJ From the documentation, Latexworkshop uses PDF.js.
It should work out of the box. On windows it works normally, the pdf is previewed in a vscode tab as expected, so maybe it's a problem with the vscode-server service. As seen in the screenshots, the pdf viewer is there, in the tab, but it shows nothing. Instead, viewing the file (on the server) using a browser tab, works normally.
Do you know ho can I solve the issue? I'm not experienced with these kind of stuff.

Comment: I have the same issue with my VScodium on Mac M1. I think it is following an update in the past week for me.